# Can't find my error

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Spvek}[2][r]{%
\gdef\@VORNE{1}
\left(\hskip-\arraycolsep%
\begin{array}{#1}\vekSp@lten{#2}\end{array}%
\hskip-\arraycolsep\right)}

\def\vekSp@lten#1{\xvekSp@lten#1;vekL@stLine;}
\def\vekL@stLine{vekL@stLine}
\def\xvekSp@lten#1;{\def\temp{#1}%
\ifx\temp\vekL@stLine
\else
\ifnum\@VORNE=1\gdef\@VORNE{0}
\else\@arraycr\fi%
#1%
\expandafter\xvekSp@lten
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{Eq:4.31}
\begin{aligned}
& \textbf{E}=-\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \textbf{A}}{\partial t}-\nabla V \\
& \textbf{B}=\nabla \cross \textbf{A}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
A guage transformation upon these potential components takes the form:
\begin{equation} \label{Eq:4.32}
\begin{aligned}
& V \longrightarrow V -\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial t} \\
& \textbf{A} \longrightarrow \textbf{A} + \nabla \Lambda
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
for some scalar field $\Lambda$, inserting this transformation into their 
defining equations gives:
\begin{equation} \label{Eq:4.33}
\begin{aligned}
& \textbf{E}=-\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial (\textbf{A}+\nabla \Lambda)}
{\partial 
t}-\nabla (V -\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial t}) \\
& =-\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \textbf{A}}{\partial t}-\cancelto{0}{\frac{1}
{c}\frac{\partial \nabla \Lambda }{\partial t}}-\nabla V-\cancelto{0}{\nabla 
\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial t}} \\
& \textbf{E}=-\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \textbf{A}}{\partial t}-\nabla V \\
& \textbf{B}=\nabla \cross (\textbf{A}+\nabla \Lambda) = \nabla \cross 
\textbf{A} + \cancelto{0}{\nabla^2\Lambda} \\
& \textbf{B}=\nabla \cross \textbf{A}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
showing invariance under these transformations, though they add a phase-like 
term to the solution to the electromagnetic wave equation i.e.:
\begin{equation}
\Psi' \longrightarrow \Psi exp[i\Lambda/\hbar c]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& i\hbar\frac{\partial\Psi_1}{\partial t}=\frac{\textbf{p}^2}
{2m}\Psi_1+eV(t)\Psi_1 \\
& i\hbar\frac{\partial\Psi_2}{\partial t}=\frac{\textbf{p}^2}{2m}\Psi_2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Results in this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.230 \begin{equation}
```

Comment: please always show a complete small document that reproduces the error. here as the error is detected on `\begin{equation}` the error is not in this equation (which has not been read yet) but a previous math construct was not properly closed.

Comment: It's a very long document, I'm unsure of how much to include.

Comment: @I.Auguste - How about (a) the part of the preamble that's relevant and (b) the five to ten lines of code that immediately precede the code block you've already posted?

Comment: start with a copy, delete everything after line 230, then delete everything before this line that you can delete while still producing the error. Most likely you will find the bad math expression while attempting to make the test file...

Comment: I've tried doing exactly that with a test file and I haven't found it

Comment: you have still only posted unconnected fragments, please edit to be a complete document that people can test

Comment: The code you've posted so far does not generate the error you're looking to fix.

Comment: the new code makes a different error: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`. if you add the missing `\begin{document}` it runs without error and does not generate the error in your question.
`

Comment: I don't know how but it works now, I didn't change anything and simply ran it in a new file and no error appeared, thank you for the help

Comment: i confirm  David Carlisle comment. after merging your code snippets in one small complete document, its not generate error. if you still have it, its source is not in provided code snippets.

Comment: don't get any error running this code, either. Both PDFlatex and xelatex compile this document.